# Return the directory of an image

Tags: javascript, image

Has it as return the directory of an image to a text field with JavaScript?

Comment: Image where? In the same HTML page? And you want the path of the URL for that image?

Comment: It is not possible to get the file full path on local machine using browser and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a webcam that captures photos and save on  computer, I need that returns the directory of pictures to a text field.